# Need to have access to params from controller inside module without passing params to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to have access to params or if not possible access to request url inside module. I know that i can pass them to method but i can't do it (need to rebuild many methods etc.)

Is there some fast way to have access to params without passing them inside methods in module ? Or i need to rebuild code ?

Comment: add your module inside helper and `include` it in the controller, then you can access params there..

Comment: You mean require my module in Application Controller ? and then include in controller that module ?

Comment: `app/helpers/your_module.rb`, in your controller where you want to use it: `include YourModule`.

Comment: thank you, i understand now, but what if i have module in lib with own class and i need to have access to params inside that lib module from controller ?
Should i move then this to helpers and change only calls to new path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class module,

```
cattr_accessor :params
```

From any of your controller,

```
before_action :set_params
```

in application controller,

```
def set_params
  YourModule.params = params
end
```

PS Untested and theoretical, hope it works ;)

Comment: I'm getting undefined method params in my module. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: Since it is `cattr`, to access it if your method is self, `params` is sufficient else `YourModule.params`

Comment: But should i create some method to initialise params inside my module class ?
I have:
module Test -> class MyClass -> cattr_accessor :params. Sorry for asking but i haven't ever used cattr_accessor

Comment: Strange thing is that it's showing me: undefined method `params=' for ... class. This equal sign is getting like a method name, that's very strange, i'm calling from application controller: MyModule::MyClass.params = params

Comment: Can you share your module structure? Try setting it from console, i tested it and it works from console..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144066/discussion-between-dawid-pr-and-md-farhan-memon).

Comment: Ok, i added other simple module and it's working ok, so from that one where i was having problem i'm calling method from this simple one module  and returning params. Don't know why i need to do this in that way but it's working :D thank you!

Comment: Can you exactly share what you did? I think writing cattr above class block and under module block like` def you_module cattr... def class end end

` should work too